# Figure out why controls aren't updated in the user interface in a Mobile Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, compact-framework

**Background**

This is a Compact Framework 3.5 Forms application. In the process of showing a form, static (this means controls placed in the form *as is*) controls are populated in the user interface thread, while ones which may need loading data, are populated in a separate thread from the user interface one.

I'm using `Control.Invoke` in order to synchronize populating controls with data in the user interface thread.

Note user interface doesn't get stuck, and it's running as expected.

**Problem**

Controls like *ListBox*, even if they've items, these aren't shown in the user interface.

Whenever an item is added, code calls `ListBox.Update` method in order to redraw it.

---

Will you give me some hint about what's happening?

**NOTE**: I could paste here some code, but I find that useless, because it's just about starting a thread by creating a one (`new Thread(...).Start()`) and, during this thread's execution, I call some form `Invoke` method.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and time.

---

**UPDATE**
I got it working if I create a control like ListBox in the synced with UI thread action using `Control.Invoke`. Anyway, I've still need to solve that when control is created using the designer, because it's easier to place controls in that way. Thanks.

Comment: How are the Controls *created*? That is to say, on what thread is the "var foo = new Control()" code executed?  You're calling Invoke to populate, but what about actual creation?

Comment: @ctacke This is in the UI thread

Comment: The controls which aren't shown are the ones added by you at runtime or the static ones who were already on the form?

Comment: Show us the code for a single control that isn't working, from creation to population.

Comment: @ctacke As I stated in my question, there's nothing to see really. Control creation is done by VS designer, and inside a thread, I call Control.Invoke.

Comment: You say there's nothing to see, but something is not working for you.  I've been writing CF apps for nearly a decade and haven't seen the problem, which indicates to me that there is, indeed, something wrong with your code.  I can only make blind guesses as to what it is without seeing code and that's just not a productive use of your time or mine.

Comment: @ctacke Thanks for your effort, during tomorrow I'll try to reproduce my code here.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, Writing here out of meta ( to avoid a witch hunt). I have been there too. Meta effect strike hard and you feel like an urge to please them. Don't! You will edit this question when you will have time, and want to. Sometimes SO is unfair. Low rep love to hammer bigger rep. This message will auto delete in 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed lots of controls that get created in a separate thread behave peculiarly or vanish altogether when they are returned to the main thread of execution. Perhaps they become orphan or ...something.

Here's what has worked best for me: Place the controls on the form (set Visible=false, Width=0, etc., if you don't want to see them) and just pass the data back from your thread. When the data comes back, populate your controls with the data. Typically, I will create a class that contains the returned values that I am looking for, and return an instance of the class.

That said, I must tip my hat and say Chris Tacke does know what he's doing. I've taken guidance from him since XP came out and I was using Outlook Express to read from Microsoft's Newsgroups.

Comment: This is exactly what I did some hours ago to solve that problem. If I don't have any option, I'll mark it as correct one.

Comment: I've marked this answer as right one because it's nearly a good hint or, at least, a confirmation of wrong/bad behaviors in multi-threaded mobile forms. Thank you.